# How to capture a leaflet / mapbox image with a geoJSON layer?

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet, mapbox

I've taken the basic leaflet-image example here:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-image/

And modified it by adding a very simple geoJSON layer to the map:

```
var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
var segLayer = L.geoJson(dataJson);
segLayer.addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(segLayer.getBounds());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fexymjy3/10/

When I hit the "Take a snapshot" button, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

I've seen the leaflet-image readme:
https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image/blob/gh-pages/README.md

Which states

> You must set L_PREFER_CANVAS = true; so that vector layers are drawn in Canvas rather than SVG or VML.

But it doesn't say *where* to set that. I tried it setting it on my segLayer, on the map, and just globally but it doesn't fix the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global)

Unfortunately, JSFiddle does not allow to share the solution (because you can't write the script tags)
So you must do that in your own web server.

```
<script>L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;</script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-image/v0.0.4/leaflet-image.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Mapbox [static maps API](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/) will be used to asynchronous imagery fetching.

Using [This link](http://staticmapmaker.com/mapbox/) and  [MapID](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-map-id/) you can see your map image preview also.

See this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/static-map-from-geojson-with-geo-viewport/) for how to use Static map API with GeoJSON.

Add your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fexymjy3/11/)

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF2aWRsb3R0IiwiYSI6IjdlNmU1ZWUyMDE5MDcwMDQ5YTNiN2IyZTIzYjZkNTg5In0.sDTxz1C0DTl3UH7AguCBXg';

var snapshot = document.getElementById('snapshot');
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([38.88995, -77.00906], 15);

var data = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Line":85,"Seg":873},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-105.68659973,43.22522736],[-105.67418671,43.14464951],[-105.67417145,43.14464569]]}}]}';

var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
var segLayer = L.geoJson(dataJson);

segLayer.addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(segLayer.getBounds());

document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var center = map.getCenter()
    console.log(map.getCenter());


    var jsonData = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "stroke-width": 4,
            "stroke": "#ff4444",
            "stroke-opacity": 0.5
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [-105.68659973, 43.22522736],
                [-105.67418671, 43.14464951],
                [-105.67417145, 43.14464569]
            ]
        }
    };

    var encodedData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    console.log(encodedData);

    var imageUrl = "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/geojson(" + encodedData + ")/" + center.lng + "," + center.lat + "," + map._zoom + "/500x300.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF2aWRsb3R0IiwiYSI6IjdlNmU1ZWUyMDE5MDcwMDQ5YTNiN2IyZTIzYjZkNTg5In0.sDTxz1C0DTl3UH7AguCBXg";

    console.log(imageUrl);

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var dimensions = map.getSize();
    img.width = dimensions.x;
    img.height = dimensions.y;
    img.src = imageUrl;
    snapshot.innerHTML = '';
    snapshot.appendChild(img);

});
```

```css
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }

.ui-button {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  z-index:1000;
  }
#map {
  width:50%;
  }
#snapshot {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;right:0;
  width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-image/v0.0.4/leaflet-image.js"></script>
<button id='snap' class='ui-button'>Take a snapshot</button>
<div id='snapshot'></div>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your very detailed answer, and it is very interesting to use the static api instead. I may explore this option further later, but the other answer was the one I was looking for to get my current solution working as easily as possible. going to upvote your answer anyway.